# Highlighting specific items on axis text in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use bolded font for the items on x-axis that contain '(' in the name, but my approach is not producing the desired result, and on the contrary, it's bolding some names that do not contain '('. Could you please see what am I missing here:

```
bold_rows <- grepl("\\(", mtcars[,1])

ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = rownames(mtcars))) +
    geom_col() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, face = ifelse(bold_rows, "bold", "plain")))
```

Here is the example data:

```
dput(mtcars) structure(list(names = structure(c(18L, 19L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 31L, 7L, 21L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 4L, 9L, 12L, 29L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 27L, 10L, 28L, 16L, 11L, 8L, 17L, 32L), levels = c("AMC Javelin", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Camaro Z28", "Chrysler Imperial", "Datsun 710", "Dodge Challenger", "Duster 360", "Ferrari Dino (Choix-3)", "Fiat 128", "Fiat X1-9", "Ford Pantera L", "Honda Civic (Choix-2)", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Lincoln Continental", "Lotus Europa", "Maserati Bora", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Merc 230", "Merc 240D", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Pontiac Firebird", "Porsche 914-2", "Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Valiant (Choix-1)", "Volvo 142E"), class = "factor"), carb = c("4", "4", "1", "1", "2", "1", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "4", "2", "1", "2", "2", "4", "6", "8", "2"), gear = c("4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "4"), am = c("1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), vs = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1"), qsec = c("16.46", "17.02", "18.61", "19.44", "17.02", "20.22", "15.84", "20", "22.9", "18.3", "18.9", "17.4", "17.6", "18", "17.98", "17.82", "17.42", "19.47", "18.52", "19.9", "16.87", "17.3", "15.41", "17.05", "18.9", "16.7", "16.9", "14.5", "15.5", "14.6", "18.6"), wt = c("2.62", "2.875", "2.32", "3.215", "3.44", "3.46", "3.57", "3.19", "3.15", "3.44", "3.44", "4.07", "3.73", "3.78", "5.25", "5.424", "5.345", "2.2", "1.615", "1.835", "3.52", "3.435", "3.84", "3.845", "1.935", "2.14", "1.513", "3.17", "2.77", "3.57", "2.78"), drat = c("3.9", "3.9", "3.85", "3.08", "3.15", "2.76", "3.21", "3.69", "3.92", "3.92", "3.92", "3.07", "3.07", "3.07", "2.93", "3", "3.23", "4.08", "4.93", "4.22", "2.76", "3.15", "3.73", "3.08", "4.08", "4.43", "3.77", "4.22", "3.62", "3.54", "4.11"), hp = c("110", "110", "93", "110", "175", "105", "245", "62", "95", "123", "123", "180", "180", "180", "205", "215", "230", "66", "52", "65", "150", "150", "245", "175", "66", "91", "113", "264", "175", "335", "109"), disp = c("160", "160", "108", "258", "360", "225", "360", "146.7", "140.8", "167.6", "167.6", "275.8", "275.8", "275.8", "472", "460", "440", "78.7", "75.7", "71.1", "318", "304", "350", "400", "79", "120.3", "95.1", "351", "145", "301", "121"), cyl = c("6", "6", "4", "6", "8", "6", "8", "4", "4", "6", "6", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "4", "4", "4", "8", "8", "8", "8", "4", "4", "4", "8", "6", "8", "4"), mpg = c("21", "21", "22.8", "21.4", "18.7", "18.1", "14.3", "24.4", "22.8", "19.2", "17.8", "16.4", "17.3", "15.2", "10.4", "10.4", "14.7", "32.4", "30.4", "33.9", "15.5", "15.2", "13.3", "19.2", "27.3", "26", "30.4", "15.8", "19.7", "15", "21.4")), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant (Choix-1)", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic (Choix-2)", "Toyota Corolla", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", "Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino (Choix-3)", "Maserati Bora", "Volvo 142E"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your `bold_rows` are all `FALSE` probably you needed `bold_rows <- grepl(..., rownames(mtcars))` eg to bold the names that contain numbers try using `bold_rows <- grepl("\\d", rownames(mtcars))`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you were still using the built-in dataset `mtcars`. You could assign it to for example df and use your code like this:

```r
df = structure(list(names = structure(c(18L, 19L, 5L, 13L, 14L, 31L, 7L, 21L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 4L, 9L, 12L, 29L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 27L, 10L, 28L, 16L, 11L, 8L, 17L, 32L), levels = c("AMC Javelin", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Camaro Z28", "Chrysler Imperial", "Datsun 710", "Dodge Challenger", "Duster 360", "Ferrari Dino (Choix-3)", "Fiat 128", "Fiat X1-9", "Ford Pantera L", "Honda Civic (Choix-2)", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Lincoln Continental", "Lotus Europa", "Maserati Bora", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Merc 230", "Merc 240D", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Pontiac Firebird", "Porsche 914-2", "Toyota Corolla", "Toyota Corona", "Valiant (Choix-1)", "Volvo 142E"), class = "factor"), carb = c("4", "4", "1", "1", "2", "1", "4", "2", "2", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "4", "2", "1", "2", "2", "4", "6", "8", "2"), gear = c("4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "4"), am = c("1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), vs = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1"), qsec = c("16.46", "17.02", "18.61", "19.44", "17.02", "20.22", "15.84", "20", "22.9", "18.3", "18.9", "17.4", "17.6", "18", "17.98", "17.82", "17.42", "19.47", "18.52", "19.9", "16.87", "17.3", "15.41", "17.05", "18.9", "16.7", "16.9", "14.5", "15.5", "14.6", "18.6"), wt = c("2.62", "2.875", "2.32", "3.215", "3.44", "3.46", "3.57", "3.19", "3.15", "3.44", "3.44", "4.07", "3.73", "3.78", "5.25", "5.424", "5.345", "2.2", "1.615", "1.835", "3.52", "3.435", "3.84", "3.845", "1.935", "2.14", "1.513", "3.17", "2.77", "3.57", "2.78"), drat = c("3.9", "3.9", "3.85", "3.08", "3.15", "2.76", "3.21", "3.69", "3.92", "3.92", "3.92", "3.07", "3.07", "3.07", "2.93", "3", "3.23", "4.08", "4.93", "4.22", "2.76", "3.15", "3.73", "3.08", "4.08", "4.43", "3.77", "4.22", "3.62", "3.54", "4.11"), hp = c("110", "110", "93", "110", "175", "105", "245", "62", "95", "123", "123", "180", "180", "180", "205", "215", "230", "66", "52", "65", "150", "150", "245", "175", "66", "91", "113", "264", "175", "335", "109"), disp = c("160", "160", "108", "258", "360", "225", "360", "146.7", "140.8", "167.6", "167.6", "275.8", "275.8", "275.8", "472", "460", "440", "78.7", "75.7", "71.1", "318", "304", "350", "400", "79", "120.3", "95.1", "351", "145", "301", "121"), cyl = c("6", "6", "4", "6", "8", "6", "8", "4", "4", "6", "6", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "4", "4", "4", "8", "8", "8", "8", "4", "4", "4", "8", "6", "8", "4"), mpg = c("21", "21", "22.8", "21.4", "18.7", "18.1", "14.3", "24.4", "22.8", "19.2", "17.8", "16.4", "17.3", "15.2", "10.4", "10.4", "14.7", "32.4", "30.4", "33.9", "15.5", "15.2", "13.3", "19.2", "27.3", "26", "30.4", "15.8", "19.7", "15", "21.4")), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Datsun 710", "Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant (Choix-1)", "Duster 360", "Merc 240D", "Merc 230", "Merc 280", "Merc 280C", "Merc 450SE", "Merc 450SL", "Merc 450SLC", "Cadillac Fleetwood", "Lincoln Continental", "Chrysler Imperial", "Fiat 128", "Honda Civic (Choix-2)", "Toyota Corolla", "Dodge Challenger", "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28", "Pontiac Firebird", "Fiat X1-9", "Porsche 914-2", "Lotus Europa", "Ford Pantera L", "Ferrari Dino (Choix-3)", "Maserati Bora", "Volvo 142E"), class = "data.frame")

bold_rows <- grepl("\\(", df[,1])

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = mpg, x = rownames(mtcars))) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, face = ifelse(bold_rows, "bold", "plain")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Quinten, thanks for the valuable suggestion. It has to be something with the code itself, as it doesn't work with my original data either.

Comment: Hi @GhoseBishwajit, Maybe you could create a [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)? This can help you and others to share reproducible examples?